# Java MVC ActionListener NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception, actionlistener

I'm still new at using MVC and using ActionListener is giving me an issue running the program in which case where the NullPointerException comes as output.

The aim is have a back button which returns the user from the Second Menu to the Main Menu.

When i commented out this line on the Controller the error goes away. 
*this.theView.addComBackButtonListener(new CompanyBackBtnListener());*

Correct me if im wrong but i think it can't seem to find the CompanyBackBtnListener even if its there.

- Check for typos already.

I tried to narrow down the codings. If i miss any details
If you have any solutions please tell me how as i'm still learning Java.
Thank You.

**The View**

```
public class HRMSViewGUI extends JFrame {

//Declarations here

private JButton exitCusBtn;


// Main Menu
public HRMSViewGUI()
        {
            this.setTitle("Human Resource Management System");
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setSize(600,225);
            this.setResizable(false);
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            this.add(HRMSMenu);

            // Main Menu GUI/Buttons place here.
            // This contains the Main Menu buttons and GUI only.

// Second Menu
public void comMenu(){
               comFrame = new JFrame();
               comFrame.setTitle("Company Menu - HRMS SYSTEM");
               comFrame.setResizable(false);              
               comFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
               comFrame.setSize(600,225);
               comFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
               comFrame.setVisible(true);

               // Swings Codings... Buttons.

               // This is the Back/Return button.
               GridBagConstraints cusConc = new GridBagConstraints();
               exitCusBtn = new JButton("Exit to Menu");
               exitCusBtn.setToolTipText("Go back to the Main Menu.");
               cusConc.gridx = 3;
               cusConc.gridy = 8;
               cusConc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
               cusConc.insets = new Insets(5,0,0,0);
               cusContainer.add(exitCusBtn,cusConc);
        }

    void addComBackButtonListener(ActionListener listenerforComBackButton){
            exitComBtn.addActionListener(listenerforComBackButton);
    }
}
```

**The Controller**

```
public class HRMSControlGUI {
    private HRMSViewGUI theView;
    private HRMSModel theModel;

    public HRMSControlGUI(HRMSViewGUI theView, HRMSModel theModel){

        this.theView = theView;
        this.theModel = theModel;

         //set Listener for the Controller to detect the ActionListener of the View.
        this.theView.addComBackButtonListener(new CompanyBackBtnListener());
    }        

private class CompanyBackBtnListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Enable Main Menu
        theView.setEnabled(true);
    }
```

**Main**

```
public class HRMSapp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HRMSViewGUI theView = new HRMSViewGUI();
        HRMSModel theModel = new HRMSModel();
        HRMSControlGUI theController = new HRMSControlGUI(theView, theModel);
        theView.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He means `exitComBtn` needs to be created before `addComBackButtonListener` is called. You need code like `JButton exitComBtn = new JButton("Click me!");` to run before the call to `addComBackButtonListener`.

I'm not sure what the overall design of the application is but try putting the button declaration in the `HRMSViewGUI` constructor.  That way the button is created as the GUI is created (if that is is what you want).

Comment: i wanted the exitComBtn to be created on the comMenu which is the second menu. So it will return me from the second menu to the main menu.

Comment: @Mark.  Ok should be able to add the actionListener right after declaring exitComBtn.  Only thing is your listener class is a private class in the controller. You may need to move it out of there so the view class can see it.

Comment: the actionListener for the exitComBtn is already declared at the bottom of Controller

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the variable `exitComBtn` is not yet set when the `addComBackButtonListener` method is called in your controller. Probably because you create it in the `comMenu` method, which is not called in the controller (or at least not before `addComBackButtonListener` is called).